# When I forward emails, the delete key does not work when trying to remove highlighted sentences

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

The Delete key works on MS Word and on other applications and the web but not in Outlook. When I hit the Delete key at the bottom of screen it says "Delete Box yes or no" so I say yes and nothing happens.

I've been using Microsoft Outlook Pro 2003 for a long time, years and this is the first time this has happened. People have been telling me to check the "write over text" box and uncheck anything using WordPerfect, but that hasn't helped.

I use Windows 8 on a new HP Envy, which I got 18 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities ([according to this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/microsoft-outlook-and-word-delete-button/)):

#### You turned to Word Perfect shortcuts

Solve this by doing the following in MS Word:

- Select Tools in the main menu
- Select Options from the drop down
- Select the General tab

#### Some other Microsoft option turned on you

Solve this by doing the following in MS Word and/or in MS Outlook:

- Select Tools in the main menu
- Select Options from the drop down
- Select the Edit tab
- Turn **ON** the toggle for "typing replaces selection".

*Makes my wonder why all those gazillion options are there anyway...*